# run javascript external link and even internal in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, eval, getscript

How many ways are to excute javascrpit code in ajaxed page ? 
internal and externally ...
I really need to execute my scripts but found no way to my goal
I tried eval in a loop & getscript method etc ... but no result 
is there a real way to execute my scripts ?
I'm using load function to load my page please help me
I have google map it work in usual way but when I use ajax to load it, it won't work
here's my code

```
$('ul li a').on("click",function() {
    var link = $(this).attr("href") + " #contentx";
    $('#contentx').fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $('#contentx').load(link, function(){     
            $("#mapjs").each(function(i) {
                eval($(this).text());
            });
            $('#contentx').fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Avoid using `eval`. `$.getScript` works great for me. What do you mean by "no way to my goal"? Any errors?

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev please wath my website http://wearesevil.com/?page_id=16    and load contact us via ajax .... it won't work anymore

Comment: The page is in Arabic. I am not sure I can find "contact us" button there :)

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev bro we are not arab , it's persian . i change it to "contact us" please check it

Comment: You have got some errors in JS. It is not working :(

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev yes and my customer want this map .. any idea ? :(

Comment: You have no div with id `aboutus`. It fails at this point. What about AJAX, I have got no idea :( I would make an answer, if I had.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev yeah:( any idea to load maps ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to move your JS block (`<script id="mapjs">...</script>`) into its own dedicated file.

If you're using `$.load` with a landing page fragment (i.e. a URL followed by #id), then any script tags will be removed, and not executed. See the Script Execution section of the [$.load documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Psuedo-code - the 'proper' way would be be something like this:

```
$('ul li a').on("click",function() {
    var link = $(this).attr("href") + " #contentx";
    $('#contentx').fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $('#contentx').load(link, function(){
            if($(this).attr('href') == 'http://wearesevil.com/?page_id=16'){     
                $.getScript('/map.js', function(){
                    $("#mapjs").each(function(i) {
                        eval($(this).text());
                    });
                });
            }
            $('#contentx').fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });
    return false;
});
```

The 'hacky' way? You could change your `<script id="mapjs">` to be `<div id="mapjs" style="display:none;">...</div>`. This wouldn't then be removed from the DOM, and you could use `eval()` on the text.

Comment: thanks you dave .. could you see my source ? http://wearesevil.com/?page_id=16      am i in the right way ?

Comment: @Prince Yep, I had a look at your source and had a bit of a play. When you call `$("#mapjs").each(function(i) {` on line 200, `$('#mapjs')` is a length of 0  - it doesn't exist, as it gets stripped out by jQuery. If you run [this](http://pastebin.com/ruc4JyjZ) snippet in your F12 console, you'll see that 'r' (line 3) is the HTML. The `<script id="mapjs">` could be a dif with `display:none;`, and it _should_ just work.

Comment: it's make me feel embarrassed to say i still can't fix my issue ... i did what u said but i didn't understand your hacky way ... u mean i get my script after loading page via getscript() and put <div id="mapjs"> in my page ? i change my code if u see but it still doesn't work

Comment: @PrinceHack Site looks OK to me at the minute, but you're now using an IFrame? Basically, you're problem is that you're using `$.load('blah.html #foo', function(){...});`. The `#foo` part means that any `script` tags in the loaded page will not be executed.  The site looks OK to me now though - are you having a different problem? If so, it should be a new question ;).

Comment: tnx a lot man your answer helped me btw i use iframe for maps but i used your answer for fix my mesh effect in another page ... tnx dude

Answer (score 0):

> i tried eval in a loop
>   This really should work, could you post the code that you used?

You can run javascript from another source with the eval() function.

i.e:

```
eval("alert(\"hello world\")");
```

Would show a message hello world.

Comment: so much thanks for your answer .i knew this but i want to run a script and that won't work ... please watch my site (map part) http://wearesevil.com/?page_id=16.  it work but won't work on load page via ajax

Answer (score -1):

I would say that you problem is caused by the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

It is even mentioned in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/) for $.load

You may simply check debug console in Firefox or Chrome for related error message.

For example in Firefox there will be reported something like:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at https://maps.google.com. (Reason: CORS header
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

Comment: no it's not because i'm using same domain and protocol